# PostgreSQL model for user with multiple profiles

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

A user can have 3 types of profiles: A, B, C

For each type of profile, a user can have a different name, set of photos, and description.

How should this be modeled?

- will mostly be fetched by one type at a time e.g. get a user's A profile
- fields are not filtered on e.g. no filtering where name =
- no roles/permissions to worry about
- UI allows users to update either name or photos or description at a time for a profile

Separate columns in a single table:

```
profile
---
name_A name_B name_C photos_A photos_B photos_C description_A description_B description_C
```

Join another table:

```
profile
---
A_profile_id B_profile_id C_profile_id

A_profile
---
id name photos description

B_profile
---
id name photos description

C_profile
---
id name photos description
```

jsonb by field:

```
profile
---
name{A,B,C} photos{A,B,C} description{A,B,C}
```

jsonb by profile type:

```
profile
---
A_profile{name,photos,description} B_profile{name,photos,description} C_profile{name,photos,description}
```

Nested jsonb (tempting...):

```
profile
---
profile{A{name,photos,description},B{name,photos,description},C{name,photos,description}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have a fixed set of different profiles, then playing to the strength of a relational database should lead you to choose the "Join Another Table" option.

Each of the other options is slightly more flexible but essentially just a denormalized version of that.

Comment: Are you suggesting exactly what I have in "Join Another Table" option or did you mean a 1-to-many or junction table like what @Gordon Linoff suggests?

Comment: Your "join another table" option is effectively creating a junction table (the 'profile' table)

Comment: The other answer creates a very flexible option with the classic many-to-many solution, but you have here a one-to-fixed_number relation, and it's up to you how you wish to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the profiles are the same, then my first thought is two tables:

```
create table Profiles (
    profileId serial,
    . . .
);

create table Persons (
   personId serial,
   . . .
   profile_A int references profiles(profileId),
   profile_B int references profiles(profileId),
   profile_C int references profiles(profileId)
);
```

Although there could be a good reason for having three different columns, you might also want a junction table:

```
create table personProfiles (
    personProfileId serial,
    personId int references person(personId),
    profileId int references profiles(profileId),
    profileTye <whatever>
);
```

Comment: I think I like this answer. Yes, all the profile types are the same and have those 3 columns: name, photos, description. It seems like this would be more flexible too, for example if I decide to add more profile types e.g. C, D, E (most likely won't, but still). This would be better than 3 different tables with the same columns, right?

Comment: @kayla . . . If there is the remotest possibility that you could be adding more equivalent profiles, then the junction table is the right approach.